# Determining if mid-18th century signatures are from same hand?

Tags: 18th-century, palaeography, marriage-records

All three are by the groom in an English marriage certificate.  #1 from 1751 lists him as a bachelor; #2 from 1758 lists him as a widower; #3 from 1763 does not specify a marital status.  All are from Kent.  #1 and #2 are from the same parish.  #3 is from a different parish but not far.

We are trying to determine whether the same person was married more than once for the purpose of constructing a family tree.

[image: marriage certificate signatures]

Comment: Are you 100% positive that these are truly originals? Many of the records I have used from the same time period, but in the US, are copies by the town clerk because the originals were deteriorating.

Comment: Thank-you for this.  Yes it is worth considering that the signatures are forgeries, in which case no conclusions can be drawn by the comparison.  These are from the UK.  I think they are originals, but I think the clerk may have forged the signatures.  In two cases it was the same clerk.